# how remove Apple support screen sharing software

Tags: install, logs, screen-sharing, remote-control

I contacted the Apple support team and the technician asked me to install a software on my macbook so as to share my screen with him. I granted "record screen" permission to this software.

A few hours later I wanted to uninstall this software but I can't find any trace of it. It is no more visible in the "record screen" permission settings. So I bet it was removed silently at the end of the session.

According to logs it seems to be called something like "apple-scc"

How can I ensure this software was completely removed ?

I'm running Catalina 10.15.6 on a Macbook PRO 2019

thanks

Comment: What software did you install at first?

Comment: That sounds really strange.  Messages has the ability to share your screen with other Messenger users. I connect to and help support my Father from time to time this way. Can you check your ~.Library/LaunchAgent if something is there.Or see if you have anything in System Preferences -> Users -> Login Items

Comment: I don't see anything special in ~.Library/LaunchAgent or System Preferences -> Users -> Login Items

Comment: the software was installed by clicking on a link like that: https://ara.apple.com/GetRemoteAdvisor?session_key=XXXXXXX&locale=en_US from an email received form the support

Comment: The software either comes preinstalled or uninstalls itself automatically - I'm sure your computer has been properly reverted

Comment: Yes Ezekiel that's also my opinion but I'm looking for a way to make sure of that